# keeping comments in code when deploying APIs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am creating APIs for WCF services. I need to make sure that the comments are included dll. How do I do that?

Comment: OP must be mentioning about the summary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select "XML documentation file" in the Build Options of the Project Properties and then also deploy the DLLNAME.xml-File.

Answer (score 1):

Use XML Documentation Comments, which you can later compile into a help file.

XML Documentation Comments:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

Building the help file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves an integer from somewhere.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Some integer</returns>
public int GetSomeInt()
{

}
```